# Fatal error: Call to undefined method ControllerModuleDSocialLogin

Tags: arrays, opencart, fatal-error

I'm using Opencart extention (dsociallogin_v2.3). I've install it, but when try to activate it, it shows an error.

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method ControllerModuleDSocialLogin::render()
in /home/.../admin/controller/module/d_social_login.php on line 247
```

Can you please suggest me why this is happening and how to fix it?

```
$this->load->model('sale/customer_group');

$this->data['customer_groups'] = $this->model_sale_customer_group->getCustomerGroups();

$this->response->setOutput($this->render());
}

protected function validate() {
    if (!$this->user->hasPermission('modify', 'module/d_social_login')) {
        $this->error['warning'] = $this->language->get('error_permission');
    }
```

Comment: You are most likely trying to use a module, which is not compatible with your Opencart version. Opencart no longer uses $this->render() to render its pages. I would suggest you to look for a module, which is compatible with the version of Opencart you are using.

Comment: Please specify the version of `opencart` you are using. The code shows the version is below `2.0`. And if you `opencart ` version is `2.0` or above then it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

For version Lower than 2.X use

```
$this->response->setOutput($this->render());
```

For Opencart version above 2.X then user

```
$this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('folderName/fileName.tpl', $data));
```

Comment: Hi,  i am using  
Opencart Version 2.0.2.0 i am using
do you can suggest me how to solve this ??

Comment: @NeerajSharma What's your tpl file name & also let me know in which folder it is.